# How to force A2DP bluetooth protocol versus HFP

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headphones

I've got some wireless bluetooth headsets which I really like *except* for the fact that I have little to no control over whether the bluetooth subsystem chooses A2DP (high quality music) versus the HFP (low latency skype-type hands-free) protocols.

Whenever I launch Google hangouts, for example, and I choose the microphone as the input device the bluetooth system switches the audio quality on my headset.  Using bluetooth explorer I see that it's using HFP with the SCO codec:

```
AudioDeviceCurrentProtocolName = HFP;
...
HFP = {
    AudioProtocolCodec = { AudioCodecBitrate = 64; AudioCodecName = SCO; };
```

Ok fine.  If I stop using Google hangouts *sometimes* it switches by itself back to A2DP which uses the SBC protocol (I don't think my headset supports apX):

```
AudioDeviceCurrentProtocolName = A2DP;
...
A2DP = {
    AudioProtocolCodec = { AudioCodecBitrate = 325; AudioCodecName = SBC; };
```

The problem is when Google hangouts finishes, sometimes it *doesn't* switch back to A2DP on it's own and I can't seem for the life of me to figure out why.  Restarting Chrome doesn't do it and trying various buttons on the Bluetooth Explorer also seems to have no effect.

What *has* worked sometimes in the past is to change the output sound device to the internal speakers and then back to bluetooth a couple of times which can cause the bluetooth subsystem to remove and re-add the device in A2DP mode.  However this doesn't always work and just now I had to completely re-pair the bluetooth headset to get my Macbook to finally get back to using the A2DP protocol.  Sigh.

Any help?  Anything I can do to force the hardware to choose one protocol versus another?  Anyone know what is happening when the device is removed and then re-added to the sound hardware list?  I'm on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013) running 10.11.6.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now in 2020, I've not seen this problem with the same hardware.  I assume this means that Apple has added some better software to handle the transition back to A2DP after a HFP transition.